# chatting between android/iOS app to web using firebase

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting stuck with some queries, I want to implement the chat system , in which user will post their queries from Android / iOS app. and Admin (PHP/MySQL) will receive it via Admin panel and respond them from admin panel. To implement this I searched some API i.e.[pusher](https://pusher.com/), [applozic](https://www.applozic.com) and firebase. So my question is that which one should I have to use to fulfill this requirement. Suppose if I choose the firebase then how will be the flow? i.e. 
1] android/iOS user's messages will be post on firebase database , 
2] web admin panel will fetch the desired data from database to give the response
3] response will be again stored on same database (or need separate database for each chat??) 
4]android/iOS user's app will fetch the response

is this logic correct? Correct me if I am wrong.

If provide sample code/ link then it would be helpful for me.

Comment: you have require stored small amount of data then firebase is fine.otherwise you can also used applozic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use PHP? According to my knowledge for a chat application php is not that much good. You can implement this using Firebase (Notifications, Database and many more...) You can implement this on both Android and iOS. Here are some references
[Firebase Chat Android](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat), [Firebase Chat iOS](https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how admin will reply to the user, coz admin will not have any app, he will have admin panel/webpage/email access to respond

Comment: you can also create a web application with the firebase backend. you have to design the architecture of the message mechanism as you want